# no cpickle module

Tags: python

When I tried

```
import cpikcle as pickle
```

I got an error message saying `no module named cpickle`.

Does anybody know how to get `cpickle` module?
Because I heard that `cpickle` is faster than `pickle`.

Thanks

Comment: Based on the error message I think that `cpikcle` was just a typo; not the actual code the OP was running.

Answer (score 10):

Try `import cPickle as pickle` instead. Note the upper-case **'P'**. Also, you misspelled `cPickle` as `cpikcle` in your question.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's the problem... please don't laugh at me

Comment: @Qingkun: if people laugh do not worry. Learning another language is difficult enough without having to program in it. Keep it up!

Comment: @Qingkun I wasn't laughing. Problems like that can be very frustrating!

Comment: @Judge Maygarden I didn't say you were laughing, I just tried to make myself less embarrassed. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Congratulations on 10K!, Judge.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! Now I have to figure out what these moderator tools do. ;)